# Trying to Create a method in a class to calculate the mean age of a list of people in python

Tags: python, class, methods, mean

I am trying to create a method in a class to calculate the mean age of a list in python.
Basically, say I have a list of different people called peoplelist, each person in peoplelist has a format of (height, age, gender), for example person1 = 1.77, 27, m. I need to get the sum of each persons age in the list and then divide it by the length of the list and return the result.
So far I have:

```
def __len__(self):
    return len(self.peoplelist)

def __age__(self):
    agesum = 0
    for value in self.peoplelist:
        agesum = agesum + value.age
        print(agesum)
    return agesum/len(self.peoplelist)
```

This however does not seem to work, any help or explanation why this doesn't work would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: In what way does it fail?  Also, naming it `__age__` isn't a good idea (just `age` would work fine).  double underscore names of that format are reserved for use by python for special things.  Since that's the case, it might be a little confusing for people reading the API for your class.

Comment: Could you please share the error? Or you are not getting the expected output? One variable `depthsum` seems should be `agesum`. Could you please check?

Answer (score 0):

Assuming `value.age` returns the correct value, the following should work...

```
def __age__(self):
    agesum = 0
    for value in self.peoplelist:
        agesum = agesum + value.age
    return agesum / len(self.peoplelist)
```

If not, you'll have to include the code for how you're calling the function in the original question.

Comment: I don't think it is stored as a tuple, when I've tested it, value.age does return the age integer. When I manually enter the for loop in the python shell it works, its just when I try to execute the method in the program it doesn't work. Could it be that I am executing the method wrong?

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `sum()` function:

```
def age(self):
    return sum(p.age for p in self.peoplelist) / float(len(self.peoplelist))
```

Note the `float()`; in Python 2, dividing integers gives you *floor* division (rounding down) by default. Alternatively, add `from __future__ import division` at the top of your python code to enable floating point division instead.

Note that I named the method `.age()`; use double-underscore names ("dunder") only for [special method names](http://docs.python.org/2/reference/datamodel.html#specialnames).

Answer (score 0):

If your self.peoplelist is like below:

```
[(1.77, 27, 'm'), ...]
```

Then following should work:

```
def __len__(self):
    return len(self.peoplelist)

def __age__(self):
    agesum = 0
    for value in self.peoplelist:
        agesum = agesum + value[1]
        print(agesum)
    return agesum/len(self.peoplelist)
```